# Количество неудачных авторизаций Spring

Tags: spring, авторизация, java

Добрый день.   
    Кто знает как можно узнать у spring security сколько раз клиент побывал авторизироваться. Хочу после 3х неудачных попыток вывести капчу.

Есть вот этот код, который ловит неудачную авторизацию. Но не понятно где хранить колво ошибок и самое главное, как узнать кто именно неправильно авторизировался

```
public class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

    result.put(AbstractManagementEntityService.RESULT_KEY, AbstractManagementEntityService.RESULT_VALUE_ERRORS);
    result.put(AbstractManagementEntityService.ERROR_KEY, exception.getMessage());
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(result));
    out.flush();
}
}
```

версия spring security - 3.1.4 released

**UPD** Первый раз сделал так

```
if(request.getSession().getAttribute("login_attempts")==null)
request.getSession().setAttribute("login_attempts", 0); 
else request.getSession().setAttribute("login_attempts", ((Integer)       (request.getSession().getAttribute("login_attempts")) + 1));
```

сохранял количесвто в сессии и отдавал на фронт, но начальнику не понравилось, сказал, что боты как правило без куков делают запросы и этот вариант не подходит

Спасибо

Comment: мб лучше считать какимто js скриптом на клиенте?

Comment: @Gorets я только за) просто где хранить эти данные, если клиент перезагрузит страничку?
фронт на angularjs

Comment: Чтобы придумать что делать нужно лучше описать задачу: невозможно средствами Spring определить - кто печатал на клавиатуре (какой пользователь пытался авторизоваться). Поэтому нужно уточнение - считать по одному IP, по одному логину, по одной вкладке в браузере... зачем считать? Если считать, что все клиенты заходят с более-менее мощных девайсов, то можно предложить считать тяжёлый hash из login&password на стороне клиента (в js?).
Вообще интересная задача, подозреваю, что не с того конца решать пытаемся - если есть у клиентов что защищать, так включите им Google Auth какой-нибудь и будет вам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сессии храните, она для этого и создана

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
Integer failureCount = session.getAttribute("failure_count");
session.setAttribute("failure_count", failureCount==null ? 1 : ++failureCount);
```

как-то так,

Вторая часть

> как узнать кто именно неправильно
> авторизировался

что вы имеете ввиду? имя юзера?

Comment: if(request.getSession().getAttribute("login_attempts")==null)
          request.getSession().setAttribute("login_attempts", 0);        
        else request.getSession().setAttribute("login_attempts", ((Integer)(request.getSession().getAttribute("login_attempts")) + 1));

я так и сделал, но начальник сказал, не катит, так как спам боты как правило чистят куки перед запросом

Comment: у меня еще была идея, хранить мапу с IP адресами и колвом этих запросов, но как я знаю, у многих пользователей метод request.getRemoteAddr(), может возвращать один и тот же адресс, в зависимости от провайдера

Comment: Ну тут комплексный подход в таком случае.

1) можно генерить специальный токен, запоминать его на сервере и связывать с сессией, а на клиенте передавать как hidden параметр. Если запрос пришел без этого параметра или он не верный, то сразу выдаем капчу. Также оставляем проверку описанную выше

2) Первый случай возможно поможет, но чтобы его обойти нужно будет просто вначале запрашивать страницу логина(предварительно почистив куки), брать нужные данные и опять пробывать авторизлвываться, поэтому нужно дополнительно добавить проверку по ip, как вы и писали, только значение нужно побольше сделат

Comment: 3) Бот который пытается подобрать пароль зная username! опять же достаете из request username и храните в отдельной map попытки залогиниться под этим пользователем

4) Способ с применением js( усложняем способ #1), посылаете с сервера специально сгенеренный токен, заранее привязанный к сессии, на стороне js выполняете манипуляции с этим токеном, шифруете его по спец алгоритму, перед отправкой на сервер. результат манипуляций также записываете в hidden параметр, на сервере применяете тот же алгоритм что и на клиенте сверяете правильность, если токен не правильный то выдаете капчу.

Comment: Интересный кстати вопрос, спасибо вашему начальнику)) с удовольствием узнал бы элегантное и красивое решение :) Но боюсь его просто нет.